# How to code for 'Attachment' datatype in MS Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a button in my Access 2007 form. On click, I need to open filedialog. I dont know how to attach the file selected to the 'Memo' field of a table using DAO.

**Form details**

Form : OrderForm
Field: txtManagerProfile
Button : btnFileBrowse

**Table details**

Table :ManagersProfile
Memo field : Profile

Requirement:

'Profile' in table should accept any file and save it. Once the user selects the file, I need to show a open icon near to the 'txtManagerProfile' field in the form. On clicking the open button , I need to open any file. I am not used to this requirement before. Someone pls help. I am using DAO for populating other fields in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code I have a form with a text box named `txtManagerProfile` and a button named `btnFileBrowse`.  When I click on the `btnFileBrowse` button a browser pops up that lets you browse to the file.  When you select the file, the path is stored in the `txtManagerProfile` text box.  If you double click on the `txtManagerProfile` text box the file gets opened up.

Here is the code behind the form:

```
'the open filename api
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As gFILE) As Long

' the gFILE type needed by the open filename api
Private Type gFILE
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type


Private Function FileToOpen(Optional StartLookIn) As String
    'Purpose: Calls the open file api to let the user select the file to open
    'returns: string value which contains the path to the file selected. "" = no file seleted
    Dim ofn As gFILE, Path As String, filename As String, a As String

    ofn.lStructSize = Len(ofn)
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All Files (*.*)"
    ofn.lpstrFile = Space$(254)
    ofn.nMaxFile = 255
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = Space$(254)
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 255

    If Not IsMissing(StartLookIn) Then ofn.lpstrInitialDir = StartLookIn Else ofn.lpstrInitialDir = "f:\Quoting"

    ofn.lpstrTitle = "SELECT FILE"
    ofn.Flags = 0

    a = GetOpenFileName(ofn)
    If (a) Then
        Path = Trim(ofn.lpstrFile)
        filename = Trim(ofn.lpstrFileTitle)
        If Dir(Path) <> "" Then
            FileToOpen = -1
            FileToOpen = Trim(ofn.lpstrFile)
        Else
            FileToOpen = ""
            Path = ""
            filename = ""
        End If
    End If

    FileToOpen = Path
End Function


Private Sub btnFileBrowse_Click()
   Dim MyPath As String
   MyPath = FileToOpen
   If (VBA.Strings.Len(MyPath & "") > 0) Then txtManagerProfile = MyPath
End Sub


Private Sub txtManagerProfile_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
   On Error GoTo Err_My_Click
   Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

   'IF THE FILE DOES NOT EXIST THEN DISPLAY THE MESSAGE AND EXIT THE SUBROUTINE
   If (fso.FileExists(txtManagerProfile) = False) Then
      MsgBox "THE FILE PATH IS INCORRECT.", , "ERROR: INVALID FILE PATH"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'USED TO CHECK IF THE FILE IS ALREADY OPENED AND LOCKED BY ANOTHER USER.
   Open txtManagerProfile For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
   Close #1

   Application.FollowHyperlink txtManagerProfile

Exit_My_Click:
   Exit Sub
Err_My_Click:
   If Err.Number = 486 Then
      MsgBox "YOU DO NOT HAVE THE PROGRAM INSTALLED THAT " & vbNewLine & _
             "IS USED TO VIEW THIS FILE.  CONTACT YOUR IT " & vbNewLine & _
             "MANAGER AND HAVE HIM/HER INSTALL THE NEEDED " & vbNewLine & _
             "APPLICATION.", , "ERROR: MISSING APPLCIATION"
   ElseIf Err.Number = 490 Then
      MsgBox "THE FILE PATH IS INCORRECT.", , "ERROR: INVALID FILE PATH"
   ElseIf Err.Number = 70 Or Err.Number = 75 Then
      MsgBox "THE FILE IS OPENED/LOCKED BY ANOTHER USER." & vbNewLine & _
             "THEY WILL HAVE TO CLOSE IT BEFORE YOU CAN " & vbNewLine & _
             "OPEN IT THROUGH PDC.", , "ERROR: FILE ALREADY OPEN"
   Else
      MsgBox ("ERROR MESSAGE:  " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
              "ERROR NUMBER:  " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
              "ERROR SOURCE:  " & Err.Source)
   End If
   Resume Exit_My_Click
End Sub
```

***EDIT:***

You could do something like the following to save the path into a table somewhere:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
   If (VBA.Strings.Len(txtManagerProfile & "") <> 0) Then
      DoCmd.SetWarnings False
      DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyTable (linkfile) VALUES ('" & _
                   txtManagerProfile & "')"
      DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      MsgBox "SUCCESSFULLY SAVED", , "SUCCESS"
   Else
      MsgBox "YOU MUST SELECT A FILE FIRST BEFORE SAVING", , "ERROR: NO FILE"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is VBA code that works in Access 2000, so I don't see why it wouldn't work in Access 2007.

Comment: Will u pls help me to save the file to db ? I mean the file selected shd get saved to the 'memo' field in the table. How can i achieve this

Comment: **@sabari**, I edited my answer to show you one way to save it to the table.

Comment: My requirement is to save the entire file as object in the memo field. Will u pls help me on that.

Comment: You cannot save the entire file as an object in a memo field.  You are better off storing documents on a network share in a specific location and then just save the link to the document.  Whenever you need to view the document execute the code under `txtManagerProfile_DblClick`.

Comment: So by using memo..if I save a file path C:\user\desktop\abc.txt and later if i accidently move or delete the file, this would become a problem . This is a disadvantage of memo. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct if the name of the file changes, is moved or deleted then you will not be able to open it.  Instead it will give you a message stating that the file path is incorrect.  if you are going to use this method you should have some document control measures in place.  We have been successfully using this method for years with very few issues.